# UPBGE how to replace emptys with list or dictionary

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm trying to make an Openworld game. I have a script that turns all objects to emptys to but the ground,player and camera to save space,then use a pool to call objects to positions in the world where emptys are close enough to player and once out of range send them back to the pool.At first it works well but since emptys are still objects once it gets to 5000 the game will crash. Is there a way to efficiency look through a list or dictionary for world positions in specific range and place correct objects there? (Please help if can)

Answer (score -2):

https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-add-objects-once-in-range-from-dictionary/1422979 I found the answer to my question here.

Comment: Hi, Strawberrydshake !  Glad you got an answer! BSE answers form an archive, they can't rely on links alone, because they might break. Please add a summary of the solution here, enough for other users to benefit from.